# regex for catching only upper-case matches

Tags: python, regex

I need to write a regex that will catch hashtags with capital letters and apostrophes only.

For example, "#([A-Z']+)" will catch "#IS" from the following example:

```
#IS your glass half-full or half-empty?
```

BUT unfortunately will also catch "#I" in this example

```
#Is your glass half-full or half-empty?
```

I tried this: "#([A-Z]+[^a-z]+)" but it catches "#II"

```
#IIs your glass half-full or half-empty?
```

I use python and there are other clever ways of solving this problem, but I would prefer a regex solution

Comment: You can use word boundary `#([A-Z]+)\b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\b` to indicate a word boundary. Then only entire capitalized words that start with a `#` and potentially contain an `'` will be matched:

```
"((\s|^)#[A-Z']+\b)"
```

Comment: If you want the line begining with `#` should use `"^#[A-Z']+\b"` instead

Comment: You're right, but he didn't mention whether these words will always be at the start of the string.

Comment: Actually, depending on the regular expression engine used, the anchor may not be required. In Python, `re.findall(r"#[A-Z']+\b", "#IS")` will result in a match.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful to you

```
^[A-Z]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

This will find all the Upper case letters in your input

```
([A-Z])\w+
```